# Does anyone here know what happened to the journal "Indian Journal in Number Theory"?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Does anyone here know what happened to the journal [Indian Journal in Number Theory](https://ijntindia.puzl.com/)?

We recently submitted a paper to this journal via e-mail and asked for an acknowledgment of receipt.  However, despite several follow-ups to the Managing Editor over the last few weeks, we have yet to receive a reply.

Should I try to contact another member of the journal's [Editorial Board](https://ijntindia.puzl.com/editorial-board)?

Comment: Have a look at : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/72855

Comment: @Solar acknowledgement of receipt should be essentially immediate.

Comment: Looking at the third entry from 2018 (which is the latest in their archive), this does not seem like a journal worth publishing in.

Comment: Ahh, and the 10th entry from 2017 seems to prove the same statement (the twin prime conjecture). Funny that the later one does not seem aware that they were too late.

Comment: Jose, my sincere advice is that you pursue publication elsewhere. Send the editor an email indicating you are withdrawing your submission, and try a (more) reputable journal instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you everyone for your comments.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: I looked at the archive after seeing your comments, and something I found curious was that a substantial minority of the papers appear to have nothing at all to do with number theory.